# Biblatex entries with last names first and year after authors

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently usin `biblatex` with the following settings:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

%Document stuff...

\printbibliography
```

The resulting bibliography is good looking, but I'm missing two details:

- Authors are written with the first name first (although they seem to be sorted on the last name). What I want is last names first.
- The year is put together with the journal/publisher. I want it after the authors.

For example. What I get is

> J. J. Monaghan.  “Smoothed particle hydrodynamics”. In: Reports on
>   Progress in Physics 68.8 (2005), pp. 1703–1759. issn: 0034-4885. doi:
>   10.1088/0034-4885/68/8/R01.

What I want is

> Monaghan, **J. J. (2005)**  “Smoothed particle hydrodynamics”. In:
>   Reports on Progress in Physics 68.8, pp. 1703–1759. issn: 0034-4885.
>   doi: 10.1088/0034-4885/68/8/R01.

Is it possible to do this with some settings or do I have to modify the style file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One possibility would be to simply switch to `style=authoryear`. However, this will not only change the position of the year, but also remove the label number of bibliography entries (and change the formatting of citations). Workaround: Declare `bibstyle=authoryear` and add the bibliography environment definitions of the `numeric` bibstyle.

To change the order of names, use `\DeclareNameAlias`. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) question for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,firstinits=true,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Removed package option `sorting=nyt` because this is the default for `bibstyle=authoryear`.

[image]

Comment: With  biblatex v0.9a I get `AuthorA.A.A.ButhorB.B.B. (2001). Alpha.`.