# Bibtex entries with last names first and year after authors

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texstudio

I know that this question has already been asked and I tried to use the answer of this question [Biblatex entries with last names first and year after authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36240/biblatex-entries-with-last-names-first-and-year-after-authors) but is not working :(

my code is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook} %scrbook has more options than article

\usepackage{lipsum} %easy acess to the text
\usepackage{scrhack} %patches other packages to make them work better

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{tikz}%esquema
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}%esquema

% set up document fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{setspace} %espaço titulo e texto
\usepackage{enumitem} %control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\usepackage{scrpage2} %control of page headers and footers
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %primeira frase começar mais à frente


\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{authoryear}
\bibliography{Exemploreference}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

and my bibtex file:

```
   @article{Mankai2012,
author = {Selim Mankai and Catherine Bruneau},
title = {Optimal economic capital and investment decisions for a non-life insurance company},
journal = {Bankers, Markets \& Investors},
number = {119},
year = {2012},
month = {July-August},
 }

 @article{asimit2012,
author = {Alexandru Asimit and Alex Badescu and Yurity Zinchenko},
title = {Capital requirements and Optimal Investment with Solvency Probability Constraints},
journal = {Journal of Management Mathematics},
year = {2012},
month = {March},
}
```

Could u give me some help please? Thanks :)

PS: I wanted to use `bibtex` because I can get my references by copying them from google schoolar and I have for now 20 references.

Comment: Please clarify what "is not working" means. Separately, are you sure a bibliography style file called "authoryear.bst" exists?

Comment: @Mico I wasn't  getting the bibliography with last name first and the year after the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use `biblatex` package...  This is a modified version of your MWE which works fine:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook} %scrbook has more options than article
\usepackage[autocite=inline, labeldate=true, uniquename=full,uniquelist=true, style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %easy acess to the text
\usepackage{scrhack} %patches other packages to make them work better

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{tikz}%esquema
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}%esquema

% set up document fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{setspace} %espaço titulo e texto
\usepackage{enumitem} %control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\usepackage{scrpage2} %control of page headers and footers
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %primeira frase começar mais à frente


\begin{filecontents*}{MWE3.bib}
     @article{Mankai2012,
author = {Selim Mankai and Catherine Bruneau},
title = {Optimal economic capital and investment decisions for a non-life insurance company},
journal = {Bankers, Markets \& Investors},
number = {119},
year = {2012},
month = {July-August},
 }

 @article{asimit2012,
author = {Alexandru Asimit and Alex Badescu and Yurity Zinchenko},
title = {Capital requirements and Optimal Investment with Solvency Probability Constraints},
journal = {Journal of Management Mathematics},
year = {2012},
month = {March},
}
  \end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{MWE3.bib}   
\begin{document}



%\bibliographystyle{authoryear}
%\bibliography{MWE3}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: and is it possible to put number on the references? I tried to use bibstyle=numeric in the code above, but now it doesn't give the author year style.

Comment: @MarianadaCosta, you're welcome. Just replace (in the `biblatex` options): `labeldate=true` by `labelnumber=true` and `style=authoryear` by `style=numeric`.